# Failed to mkbundle Mach-o executable that can be run and codesigned successfully on MacOS

Tags: macos, mono, code-signing-certificate, mach-o, mkbundle

I'm facing a dead end trying to create MacOS mach-o executable that works.

created simple console application in visual studio; simple.exe

I've tried 2 routes with mkbundle:

using mkbundle the

## 1. the old (--custom) way:

after setting extra CC compiles args , and PATH for pkg-config:

```
$ mkbundle --deps -v  -L "$PWD" -L "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/4.5" -o $BASE/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/simple_exe ./simple.exe
```

The produced simple_exe **fails** to start:

```
$ cd $BASE/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/
$ ./simple_exe
Segmentation fault: 11
```

though, it's perfect mach-o for the OS, so signing this file succeeds.

## 2. using (--simple) mkbundle by either --cross or --sdk options:

```
$ mkbundle -v --simple --cross mono-6.8.0-osx-10.9-x64 -o $BASE/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/simple_exe ./simple.exe
```

The compiled (well, rather say constructed) executable runs successfully:

```
$ cd $BASE/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/
$ ./simple_exe
Hello World!
```

the resulting executable is signed by Xamarin

tried 2 options for deployment process:

### A- Leaving the executable it as is; signed by Xamarin's Application Certificate

- Code sign other assets beside this executable with my Application Certificate.
- Signing The whole App bundle succeeds `$codesign --strict --sign "$CERT" $BASE/Simple.app`
- Making installer .pkg and signing it with Installer Certificate succeeds.

Now, Notarization from apple result : "***Invalid***"

> issue: 
>   code  null
>
> path "Simple.pkg/pkgbuild_Simple.pkg Contents/Payload/Applications/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/simple_exe"
>
> message   "The signature of the binary is invalid."
>
> architecture  "x86_64"code    null

### B- Force resigning the bundled executable with my Application Certificate.

It gives (`__LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file (can't be processed) in: /Users/assem/bundles/SimpleApp/payload/Applications/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/simple_exe` )

I've been able to "patch" it and increasing file size inside __LINKEDIT Segment (along with aligned up VM size), and String table size under SYMTAB Load Commands to cover up injected assembles over the mkbundl*ed* Mono executable.

After Patching, I can re-sign the resulting executable with my Certificate. but, if when I run it, it outputs the mono command line options help message (As if the resulting binary was mono itself and the link/reference to the assemblies bundled inside is broken).

```
$./SimpleApp/payload/Applications/Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/Simple_exe 
Usage is: mono [options] program [program-options]

Development:
    --aot[=<options>]      Compiles the assembly to native code
    --debug[=<options>]    Enable debugging support, use --help-debug for details
    --debugger-agent=options Enable the debugger agent
    --profile[=profiler]   Runs in profiling mode with the specified profiler module
    --trace[=EXPR]         Enable tracing, use --help-trace for details
    --jitmap               Output a jit method map to /tmp/perf-PID.map
    --help-devel           Shows more options available to developers
.
.
.
.
```

etc..

note: The original Xamarin's signature was in the middle of the mkbundl*ed* O-Mach executable, then followed by simple.exe as well as dependent assemblies.
After patching and re-signing with my certificate. the code signature is attached to the end of the bundled file , beyond embedded assemblies.

**To make a long story short:**
mkbundle either compiles a (sign-able) native mach-o binary , but when it runs immediately crashes with segmentation fault. 
or, constructs a binary file the runs but fails to be deployed inside signable mac bundle and notarized installer pkg.

Stack:

- MacOS Catalina (Also tried all of the above on Mojave)
- Mono 6.8.0 (Also tried on 6.6.0 , 6.4.0, and 6.0.0)
- XCode Version 11.3.1 (also tried on older 10.x)

Comment: I have a feeling the `__LINKEDIT` issue stems from Xamarin rather than your attempted force-resigning, and it'd explain the invalid signature. You could maybe try `codesign --remove-signature` and see if that even works, or whether it complains.

Comment: Yes, _LINKEDIT stems from the fact that not counting accumulating embedded assemblies at the tail of the base of bundled mono executable. Even --remove-signature fails before patching that file.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug report tbh. There will certainly be a way to binary-patch your way to being validly signable, but I don't think that's maintainable.